# Why the gradients produced by the soft targets scale as 1/T^2 in knowledge distillation?

Tags: deep-learning, gradient

In the paper "Distilling the knowledge in a neural network", it mentioned "the magnitudes of the gradients produced by the soft targets scale as 1/(T^2) ", but it has no mathematical derivation. So how the term 1/(T^2) is calculated?

Answer (score 1):

This scaling factor is derived in Section 2.1 of the paper. $\frac{1}{T^2}$ is a coefficient for both equations (3) and (4) when calculating the derivative of the cross-entropy loss $C$ wrt a logit $z_i$. These two equations are made under some assumptions, though: the temperature $T$ has to be high compared to the logit magnitudes (for equation (3)) and that the logits need to be zero-meaned (for equation (4)).

The way you get from (2) to (3) using the temperature magnitude assumption is with the approximation: $\log(1+x) \approx x$ for small $x$. Let $x$ be $\frac{z_i}{T}$ which means:
$$\log(1 + \frac{z_i}{T}) \approx \frac{z_i}{T}$$
$$1 + \frac{z_i}{T} \approx e^{\frac{z_i}{T}}$$
Apply this to the numerators and denominators to complete the derivation.